# r data disappearing when sharing X between ggplot and plotly objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Consider the following `subplot`

```
library(plotly)

candlestick.plot <- dff %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~time_terminal, type="candlestick",
                                   open = ~open.ha, 
                                   close = ~close.ha,
                                   high = ~high, low = ~low) %>% 
  add_trace(
    data=dff,
    x=~time_terminal,
    y=~close,
    inherit=F,
    name='close',
    mode='markers',
    type='scatter',
    marker = list(
      color = 'black',
      size = 4),showlegend = F) %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = F)),
    yaxis=list(
      autorange = T,
      fixedrange= F,
      showlegend = FALSE
    ))
rsi.plot <- dff %>% ggplot(aes(x = time_terminal))+
   geom_line(aes(y = RSI), color = 'blue')
subplot(candlestick.plot, rsi.plot, nrows = 2, shareX = F)
```

[image]

As soon as I specify `shareX = T`, the candlestick data disappears. Any idea?

[image]

Also having this `Warning message: Can only have one: config`

```
dff <- structure(list(time_terminal = structure(c(1663973640, 1663973700, 
1663973760, 1663973820, 1663973880, 1663973940), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), open.ha = c(12310.0220066959, 12308.473503348, 
12306.386751674, 12303.655875837, 12306.1654379185, 12308.9202189592
), close.ha = c(12306.925, 12304.3, 12300.925, 12308.675, 12311.675, 
12305.425), close = c(12303.8, 12303.3, 12302.3, 12315.3, 12306.3, 
12301.8), high = c(12311.3, 12310.3, 12303.8, 12316.8, 12321.3, 
12312.8), low = c(12301.3, 12300.3, 12294.8, 12300.3, 12302.8, 
12300.8), RSI = c(41.4164256925358, 40.5856999623739, 38.7902017103494, 
63.2063136422104, 47.9328942864108, 42.0681730122613)), row.names = 4178:4183, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: May I ask why do you want to use `shareX = TRUE`?

Comment: Because that is required for `rangesliders`

Comment: I'd suggest [filing an issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues) or using `plot_ly()` as a workaround `rsi.plot <- plot_ly(dff, x = ~time_terminal, y = ~ RSI, color = I('blue'), type = "scatter", mode = "lines")`.